# Stopping Video Out of ViewPort - FIX HELP: Put together JavaScripts and Fix on iPad & iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I create a simple JQUERY to make videos (plural) stop when not in View Port

You can see Fiddle working here: https://jsfiddle.net/x2tpLw5g/9/

You can also see a working demo here: https://dallaswebideas.com/audio.html

**The problem I have are two.**

**1)** I would like to put together the JQUERY's as right now look like below, I am new to this so need help on this:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($("#video1").not("#video1:in-viewport").length) {
$("#video1").not("#video1:in-viewport")[0].pause();
}
});
</script> 

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($("#video2").not("#video2:in-viewport").length) {
$("#video2").not("#video2:in-viewport")[0].pause();
}
});
</script>
```

**2)** If you check the Fiddle on iPad or iPhone, it does not works

UPDATE: It only works on Firefox, I tested on Chrome and IE11 and does not works either

**Can anyone knows how to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the code I end up using.

The effect I was trying to get is

When I get to the video inside view-port, I will click play myself (the user)

But then if I move out (the user) out of view-port the video will stop.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/is-in-viewport/3.0.4/isInViewport.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('video').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
            $(this);
        } else {
            $(this)[0].pause();
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Working Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dh460c2x/5/

Live demo site is here: https://dallaswebideas.com/audio1.html